# Refit 6, net 5 error Cannot determine the frame size or a corrupted frame was received

Tags: c#, httpclient, refit

I found the following similar [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64610237/net-5-0-cannot-determine-the-frame-size-or-a-corrupted-frame-was-received) that didn't fix my issue.

I have a 5.0 console app and the `HttpClient` is being configured manually instead of using the Refit extension factory method (both ways result in the error).

Console app config, previous attempt to use refit factory extension method. I believe the answer is here somewhere...I need to find a way to define the the Ssl protocol here.

```
  var builder = 
    new HostBuilder()
        //.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        //{
        //  services.AddRefitClient<IIdentityApi>()
        //          .ConfigureHttpClient(c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:20595"));
       //})
      .UseConsoleLifetime();
```

Here is that code:

```
  var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
  {
     // tried Tls11, Tls13, None
     SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls13
  };

 var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler)
 {
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:20595")
 };

 var identityApi = RestService.For<IIdentityApi>(httpClient);
```

Stacktrace:

```
  System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
  HResult=0x80131620
  Message=The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
  Source=System.Net.Http
  StackTrace:
  ...
  Inner Exception 1:
  IOException: Cannot determine the frame size or a corrupted frame was received.
```

Comment: Were you able to understand what happened and how to fix it?

Comment: Hi @Lucas! No I didn't, I went another route.

Comment: @WillLopez would you kindly provide your solution or delete this post so that googlers like myself don't fall for this dead-end post as well? Thanks!

Comment: @JustinVanBibber Sorry but I will leave this question because it still needs an answer. My solution isn't valid as it does not pertain to the question so I won't post that as an answer - I couldn't use the library, issue was not resolved. Thanks!