# .Net 5.0 API and Let's encrypt "The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception."

Tags: api, .net-5, lets-encrypt

I have a web application developed in .Net 5.0, front-end is Blazor Server App, and back-end is Restful API, both are hosted on the same server and using Let's encrypt certificates, after October 1st 2021 the certificates were renewed after that the front-end started throwing this error:

The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
Cannot determine the frame size or a corrupted frame was received.

If I run the application from my development PC and connected to the API on the server everything works fine, when I call the API from postman it also works fine, but when I deploy the application on the server I get the above error only when the application is trying to call the API. Also, the API is being called from another services and those are also working fine.

Both API and App are hosted on Windows 2012 server running IIS, Windows is updated to latest update.

Could that be related to latest change in Let's Encrypt? Any idea how to solve this?

Regards

Ameen

Update: Results of openssl command, I replaced some parts with XXXX:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = api.**********.***
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = api.**********.***
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
   i:C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=CN = api.**********.***

issuer=C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3176 bytes and written 488 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    Session-ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1633351070
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: yes
---
```

Edit 05/10/2021: Here is the full exception:

```
2021-10-05 09:58:33.4977|ERROR|xxx.xxx.xxx.Expenses.Index|System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Cannot determine the frame size or a corrupted frame was received.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveBlobAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Boolean async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Boolean async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.AuthenticationHelper.SendWithAuthAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Uri authUri, Boolean async, ICredentials credentials, Boolean preAuthenticate, Boolean isProxyAuth, Boolean doRequestAuth, HttpConnectionPool pool, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions.GetFromJsonAsyncCore[T](Task`1 taskResponse, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at xxx.xxx.Services.ApiService.Search(Nullable`1 status, String title, String email) in D:\xxx\xxx.xxx.Services\ApiService.cs:line 60
   at xxx.xxx.Pages.xxx.Index.UpdatePage(Status s) in D:\xxx\Index.razor.cs:line 84
```

Comment: What does the inner exception say?

Comment: And use for instance `openssl s_client -showcerts your.domain:443` to check what certificate chain is served by your server

Comment: Inner exception say: Cannot determine the frame size or a corrupted frame was received.

Comment: Please add that information in a readable format to the question ...

Comment: Sorry about that, I added the result with the question.

Comment: The certificate chain looks ok. Maybe the answer to this question helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64610237/net-5-0-cannot-determine-the-frame-size-or-a-corrupted-frame-was-received

Comment: @derpirscher I came across this question previously, I don't have TLS 1.3 key in the registry neither on the server nor on my development PC, on the server there is SSL 2.0 key only.

Comment: I made the changes to registry to Enable TLS 1.1 and 1.2 by default and disable 1.3 by default, restarted the server, but that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Also tried disabling TLS 1.3 by setting Enabled to 0 from both Client and Server keys, but that didn't help either.

Comment: @AmeenNihad Were you able to find the solution?

Comment: @thewayman I moved my apps to another server running Windows 2019 server. I still don't know what was the cause of the issue.