# Blazor Net 5 The SSL connection could not be established

Tags: c#, ssl, asp.net-web-api, https, blazor-server-side

I am working on Blazor Server App, using .net 5 which connects to a .net framework 4 web API.  When I try to connect to my hosted server which is in HTTPS, I get an error in both Visual Studio and IIS in my server. When I call an API from my Blazor Server to my Web API.

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'The SSL connection could not be
> established, see inner exception.'
>
> IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An
> existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>
> SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
> remote host.

After a lot of searching, I have found no solutions

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67197777/835292
2. Added these lines on my Blazor Server App **Startup.cs** constructor.

   ```
   ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
   ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
   ```

3. Also these lines when I call the API.

   ```
   HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
   clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
   var httpClient  = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
   ```
4. Also executed this in my Dev PC

> dotnet dev-certs https --clean 
> dotnet dev-certs https --trust

None of the solutions worked for me. Please help.

**Note: My Web API is in HTTPS and my Blazor app is not**

Comment: Can you access the root of the API from a browser on the computer you are running your Blazor app from? You might get an HTTP error in the browser, but that would be good. If you get a connection error, then you know it's a network problem.

Comment: I can access the API from everywhere computers include the same computer where they are both hosted.